# How to initialize an empty array inside a struct?

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays, struct, memory

Is there a mistake in the way I initialize Bar b in the function foobar?

```
contract Foo {

    struct Bar {
        address owner;
        uint[] x;
    }

    Bar[] public bars;

    function foobar(address a) public {
        Bar storage b = Bar(a, new uint[]) // will that be an array in storage?
        bars.push(b)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no need to initialize `storage` arrays in Solidity. Only `memory` arrays has to be initialized before usage.

So in your case, no need to initialize `x` inside `Bar` as long as you are not assigning a value to one of the `x` indexes inside your `foobar`. Actually, making initialization in your code will consume gas for no reason.

The following code works well for your case:

```
function foobar(address a) public {
    Bar memory b;
    b.owner = a;
    //When 'b' is pushed to 'bars' array:
    // (1) 'b' will be converted from memory to storage.
    // (2) And 'x' inside it will be initialized automatically.
    bars.push(b); 
}
```

However, if you need to access x and push some value you can use `push`:

```
function foobar2(address a, uint x0) public {
    Bar memory b;
    b.owner = a;
    bars.push(b);
    //Trying: b.x[0] = x0; will generate error. Since, b.x is a memory array that is not initialized!
    bars[bars.length - 1].x.push(x0); //This will work fine!
}
```

Actually, you can still initialize your memory array, as an empty one, as follow:

```
function foobar3(address a) public {
    Bar memory b = Bar(a, new uint[](0)); //Thanks to "James Duffy" for his answer.
    bars.push(b);
}
```

---

Last thing to mention is that: If you have multi values, that you need to insert to your `x` array, then you can do this as follow:

```
function foobar4(address a, uint[] _x) public {
    Bar memory b = Bar(a, _x);
    bars.push(b);
}
```

Or as follow. But, this will consume more gas:

```
function foobar5(address a, uint[] _x) public {
    Bar memory b;
    b.owner = a;
    bars.push(b);

    Bar storage c = bars[bars.length - 1]; // Get the newly added instance of the storage struct
    for (uint i = 0; i < _x.length; i++) {
        c.x.push(_x[i]);
  }
```

---

Check full code at the nice EthFiddler: https://ethfiddle.com/fQI6Khgz3E

Comment: Welcome. And thanks to Georgios Konstantopoulos and Loom Network: https://medium.com/loom-network/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-how-to-initialize-an-array-inside-a-struct-184baf6aa2eb

Comment: After calling foobar, foobar2 or foobar3, I get value of bars[0] == {owner: *address*} without  property x at all!!! It's completely ignored. How is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I figured out why this is happening. Need to have separate getter in order to receive arrays from structs like getXFromBar

Answer (score 3):

Working fiddle:

https://ethfiddle.com/Yn6fLiAjto

One way to make this work is to create your temporary `Bar` in memory before pushing it to `bars` (`Bar memory b` instead of `Bar storage b`). Solidity will then automatically copy the struct data from memory to storage. See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4476/22415 for more details.

Also `new uint[]` is a function which requires a size argument, e.g. `new uint[](8)`.

So in full, that line should read `Bar memory b = Bar(a, new uint[](8));`

Comment: I see! So I cannot assign a dynamically sized array to the struct while initializing it?

Comment: any answers yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Address {
    address[] addressList;
}

function createProposal() public {
    address[] memory emptyAddressList;
    Address memory _address = Address({
       addressList: emptyAddressList
    })
}
```